# SQL Anywhere , Ubuntu 12.04 x86

Tags: plugins, sql

I need to make a server in my company. IMG of my MNC has refused to provide any help on Linux systems, hence I need to do it without any help.

I tried:
⠀Ubuntu 13.10 x86, SQL Anywhere(12-16) both Linux and Windows setup (used Wine)
⠀Ubuntu 11.10 x86, SQL Anywhere(12-16) both Linux and Windows setup (used Wine)
⠀Ubuntu 12.04 x86, SQL Anywhere(12-16) both Linux and Windows setup (used Wine)

If I'm using a Linux setup and open using scjview, it is showing libjys----.r.so and etc. error, and I'm not able to make UltraLite Database or any plugin though SQL is running.

Whereas in case I'm using Wine to use the Windows setup for SQL, it shows 5 errors, all plugin errors mlpulguin, ulpluginm, etc., and cannot see any plugin in SQL.

Hence I'm in deep trouble.

I tried both versions of SQL Anywhere (the client as well as the server one).

I wish to know: has someone done it before? If you have, I need to know exactly the way of getting it done.

Answer (score 0):

After the install, you need to source the sa_config.sh file that is installed in the SQLAnywhere bin32/64 directory.  This will set up your path and environment variables so you can run scjview.
On Windows, everything should be properly setup by the install program, assuming you chose to install the tools and plugins during the setup process.  You may have to restart the emulator for it to pick up the environment changes though (I don't know a lot about Wine).

Comment: ya i dot it, after a lot of research i found the same thing. sa_config.sh has all the environment variable.
so i tried running it. it ran, but it was still not working showed the same plugins problems.
hence i retried every step of of that .sh file manually on terminal and rechecked all the SQLANY12 variable etc. which was all working fine. but program still not running,
also just to be extremely certain i installed java 1.6.0 sun official and made it default for the system but still the same problem,
thank you so much for ur help but i need a new idea for progress..